# Entry requirements for U.S. Virgin Islands (for US citizen)

Tags: us-citizens, us-virgin-islands

https://www.vimovingcenter.com/getting_there/documents/ says U.S. citizens can enter the USVI without a "passport or proof of citizenship" if arriving from a US airport.

But doesn't that in effect mean anyone can enter if they pass through a US airport (by claiming to be a US citizen)?

I realize you won't get on the plane to go there without **something**; are they checking airline data for citizenship info?

Comment: You can also enter California without a passport if you come from another US airport or across a land border with another state. This is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Before issuing a boarding pass, the airline will check. This will be done in the same manner as an international flight, to make sure the passenger can enter the destination.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica The airline is going to check travel documents on a domestic flight?! I can't say that has ever happened to me. Then again I haven't flown to USVI yet...

Comment: @ThePhoton: I think the point the OP may be trying to get at is that it seems to say that non-citizens need a passport to go to US territories from a US airport, and this seems easy to circumvent since US citizens don't; whereas this situation doesn't exist with travel within the states, where both citizens and non-citizens do not need a passport.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Timatic produces the regular, extensive who-can-enter information for the USVI. This info changes when traveler nationality is changed, and Timatic lists USVI as a distinct destination. In addition, flights arrive in the USVI from other-than-US origins. We know the airline must fly a nonadmissible person back. From all these, I conclude _someone_ must check. OTOH, I haven't been to the USVI either.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I can certainly see airlines checking Timatic when flying there from outside the US, but for a purely domestic flight?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Anywhere-in-the-US to St. Thomas is a domestic flight for US citizens. But non-US citizens may buy tickets on that flight too. The airline must check every passenger to assure itself that they're not carrying a passenger who'll have to be flown back to the US.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica What do you mean, "back to the US"? The USVI is part of the US!

Comment: @MichaelHampton It is part of the US, but Timatic's data changes if the traveler's information changes. The deleted answer from mlc asserted that if one is authorized to be in the US, one is authorized to be in the UKVI. Were that true, it would disprove my thesis, but the answer was very quickly deleted by the author, and phoog's comment (citing a source in the original question) confirms that some travelers to the UKVI cannot fly back to mainland US. All this is consistent with different UKVI entry requirements for non-US citizens. That means that checking must occur before flight departure.

Comment: @user102008 gets it.  Of course, getting there is the problem, but if you somehow got past that, you'd only have to claim you are a citizen and not be asked to prove it.  Doesn't make sense.  Then again, it's not a government website.

Comment: The webpage also states (close to the bottom) that non-US citizens should follow the same entry rules and requirements as the US. So I imagine that to able to get into the US in the first place would satisfy the USVI.

Comment: Or maybe the people producing this unoffical site are hinting to non-citizens that they should lie?

Comment: Who is "they"? Airlines or customs officials? I think your last question needs some clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Traveling to the USVI is considered leaving the mainland and will require you to re-enter the USA when returning from USVI. Essentially, when you leave the mainland, you will need to clear immigration when you return.

You do not need a passport to travel domestically within the United States (mainland or not). Government issued id is acceptable (like a drivers license,  state id, etc).

In order to depart on any US domestic flight, you must show a valid government issued id.

To exit USVI you must present either 1.) A valid US passport or 2.) A "raised seal" birth certificate and also a government issued id (like drivers license, state id, etc.)

Nobody is checking what documents you depart the mainland with. It is up to you to have the correct documents to return to the US mainland. They assume you have presented id when you booked your flight to USVI and it is the correct one you'll need to return on.

Nobody is checking airline data for citizenship info. If I held a Russian passport, booked a domestic USVI round trip from mainland and back, I will have to present my Russian passport when I arrive on the mainland.

If I hold a US passport, but travel with my state issued id instead, I will need to have my birth certificate handy upon returning to the mainland, if I do not have my passport on me.

For US citizens, they are not as concerned about entry into USVI as much as the re-entry to the mainland United States.

Comment: USVI is quite unusual in that CBP checks passengers departing to elsewhere in the United States, not passengers arriving from elsewhere in the United States. The reason for this is a high number of illegal immigrants from DR who attempt to fly out to the mainland. Of course they also check international arrivals, but that's not in scope here.

Comment: Detailed information, but doesn’t address the question.

Comment: @WGroleau what exactly is your question? There are no entry requirements. You book a flight, you show id. So what exactly is your question???

Comment: There are two question marks there.  If it’s not clear, I’ll have to let someone else edit, because it’s quite obvious to me.